# Django update one field using ModelForm

Tags: python, django

**How do I update just one field in an instance using ModelForm if the POST request has only that one field as parameter**? ModelField tries to override the fields that were not passed in the POST request with None leading to loss of data.

I have a model with +25 fields say

```
class C(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
    x = models.IntegerField()
```

and I have a desktop application that does POST requests in order to edit an instance of C through an exposed api method in views.py

In the api method I am using ModelForm to validate the fields as follows:

```
form = CModelForm(request.POST, instance=c_instance)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

When doing save() django either complains that some other field cannot be null or (if all fields are optional) overwrites them with None.

Does somebody know how to manage it? I would do all checks manually and update manually, but the model has so freakishly long list of fields...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a subset of the fields in your ModelForm by specifying those fields as follows:

```
class PartialAuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title')
```

From the docs:

> If you specify fields or exclude when creating a form with ModelForm,
>   then the fields that are not in the resulting form will not be set by
>   the form's save() method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form

Comment: the problem is I do not know which field are going to be updated :-/

Answer (score 19):

Got this figured. What I do is update the request.POST dictionary with values from the instance - so that all unchanged fields are automatically present. This will do it:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from copy import copy

def UPOST(post, obj):
    '''Updates request's POST dictionary with values from object, for update purposes'''
    post = copy(post)
    for k,v in model_to_dict(obj).iteritems():
        if k not in post: post[k] = v
    return post
```

and then you just do:

```
form = CModelForm(UPOST(request.POST,c_instance),instance=c_instance)
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function) yet.

You can easily achieve partial form updates by creating a specific version of a form class, defining the subset of fields you're interested in:

```py
from django.forms import modelform_factory

...

foo = get_object_or_404(Foo, slug=foo_slug)

if request.method == "POST": 
    PartialFooForm = modelform_factory(
        Foo, form=FooForm, fields=("my_first_field", "my_second_field",)
    )
    form = PartialFooForm(request.POST, instance=foo)
    if form.is_valid():
        foo = form.save()
        return redirect(foo)
else:
    form = FooForm(instance=foo)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, Niko—it worked like a charm. Definitely the best solution I've come across to address this issue.

Comment: If you want to reduce some maintenance, an option in some circumstances would be to use "fields=PartialFooForm.base_fields.keys()"

Answer (score 2):

Django's `ModelForm` isn't designed to handle a partial update of an arbitrary subset of fields on the model.

The use case described by the OP, a desktop app hitting an API, would be handled better by [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Specifically, you would create a serializer that inherits from `ModelSerializer`, and then use it in an `UpdateAPIView`. Serializers in DRF are analogous to forms in Django.

If you don't mind adding another dependency with DRF, which is a really great library, this probably beats rolling your own solution.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'


class MyModelDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm very late to the party, but could you create a factory function for the form.

```
def model_form_factory(cls, data, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Create a form to validate just the fields passed in the data dictionary.

    e.g. form = form_factory(MyModel, request.POST, ...)

    """


    data = data.copy()
    data.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken', None)

    class PartialForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model  = cls
            fields = data.keys()

    return PartialForm(data, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this similar to Roman Semko's answer (which may not work with ManyToMany fields):

Alter your form's `__init__` method to update the data:

```
import urllib

from django import forms
from django.http import QueryDict
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class MyModelForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # if form has being submitted and 
        # model instance exists, then get data

        if self.is_bound and self.instance.pk:

            # get current model values
            modeldict = model_to_dict( instance )
            modeldict.update( self.data.dict() )

            # add instance values to data
            urlencoded = urllib.urlencode( modeldict )
            self.data = QueryDict( urlencoded )
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you must create method to init form with absent data in your request, something like:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    ... your model ...

    def initial(self,data):
        fields = [list of possible fields here]

        for field in fields:
            if data.get(field) is None:
                data[field] = getattr(self,field)

        return data
```

Then, pass this data in your form like:

```
form = MyForm(instance.initial(request.POST.copy()),instance=instance)
```

for JSON:

```
from json import loads

form = MyForm(instance.initial(loads(request.body)),instance=instance)
```